# Adding folders to rails public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a folder containing javascript, html, css, images and similar files in the root folder of my Rails 5 project.

I want to serve that folder as if it had been in the public directory, instead of the root.

Am currently serving the files through a controller, but that do not seem like a good solution. Is there any way I can serve the files from a different folder as if they were in the public folder, without moving the files.

There is a lot of files, and most of them are rarely used, so I dont want to compile them to the assets files.

(I do have other content in the public folder, and do not just want to change what is the public folder)

Comment: How about serving them directly from your webserver without even touching rails? That can be achieved with nginx or apache setting the root to that particular folder. You could also create a symbolic link in the public folder pointing to these special assets. That way you wouldn't have to move anything into public, but it would behave as if the content was there.

Comment: “that does not seem like a good solution” — okay, how come? What you're doing is already pretty iffy, not sure that using a controller to achieve it is more onerous or offensive.

Comment: Also, *why not just move the folder to the `public` folder?*

Comment: The files is generated by other programs on the server and am not able to change the output location.

Comment: If you're using an OS that supports symbolic links, I think it's the way to go. Doing it through the controller will make those requests go through the Rails stack for no good reason. It is definitely more onerous than serving them in the public folder.